# Disallowed implicit conversion from data type datetime to data type float

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROC proc_tblBillRegisterExtended (@FromDate AS DATETIME, @ToDate AS DATETIME, @CustomerID AS NUMERIC = NULL, @UnitLoc AS NUMERIC = NULL)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BillRegister 
        SELECT *  FROM BillMain BM 
            JOIN BillDetails BD ON BM.BillMainID = BD.BillMainID 
            JOIN ProductMaster PM ON BD.ProductID = PM.ProductID 
            JOIN CustomerMaster CM ON CM.CustomerID=BM.CustomerID 
            JOIN EnumCollections EC ON (BM.Status = EC.ENUMVALUE AND EC.EnumType =1) 
        WHERE 
            BM.UnitLoc = @UnitLoc 
            AND BM.BillDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT * FROM FROM BillMain BM 
            JOIN BillSampleDetails BSD ON BM.BillMainID = BSD.BillMainID 
            JOIN ListMaster LM ON BSD.SampleID = LM.ListID 
            JOIN CustomerMaster CM ON CM.CustomerID=BM.CustomerID 
            JOIN EnumCollections EC ON (BM.Status = EC.ENUMVALUE AND EC.EnumType =1)
        WHERE 
            BM.UnitLoc = @UnitLoc 
            AND BM.BillDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate 
END
```

I am getting following 
Disallowed implicit conversion from data type datetime to data type float, table dbo.BillRegister', column 'SGSTPer'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

But DataType of SGST is not datetime in sourse table

please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please, please **please** reformat that awful SQL. Posting your ENTIRE query on a single line makes it completely unreadable.

Comment: ... and while you're at it, reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: I new here. Please help me

Comment: Show how `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` are declared

Comment: You have the syntax `SELECT * FROM FROM BillMain BM `. `FROM FROM` isn't valid syntax. Also, as you have used SELECT *, we can't see what columns are being used. Can you post your DDL for your tables please?

Comment: *"I new here"* ... but member of this site for more than 3 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have missed mapping of column vs values. Please pass your values in correct sequence as per BillRegister table columns.

Thanks,
Amrut